# What are the differences between these two queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

The title speaks for itself. The first query -

```
SELECT    *
FROM      table _t
WHERE     (id1, id2, id3, id4) <> (x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

The second query -

```
SELECT    *
FROM      table_t
WHERE     NOT
          (id1 = x1 AND
           id2 = x2 AND
           id3 = x3 AND
           id4 = x4)
```

What are the differences between these two queries (i.e., is there any performance gain/loss or something) ?

**Edit**

To all those who think I am joking or something, I just want to say that I have used both queries in postgresql 8.4. **Both queries work just fine**.

Comment: Yikes! I was not aware of the first syntax. Is this MySql?

Comment: Any performance difference is probably dependent on the database engine.

Comment: @Lieven - they're called row constructors. They're in standard SQL, and gradually creeping into MS SQL Server - for instance, you can now specify multiple rows in the VALUES clause of an INSERT using row constructors.

Comment: @Close Voter: Care to explain why you think this question should be closed?

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed - I apologize but (there's always a but) 1. you should have added tags to identify your database (it isn't valid SQLServer 2005 syntax) and 2. If you know *this much*, something many of us clearly don't, viewing a plan shouldn't be a problem for you either and you could solve your own question.

Comment: @Sayem, I voted to close *before* I knew it really was valid syntax. I can't seem to remove the vote.

Comment: @Sayem Ahmend, I read the (awesome!) article, but I'm having trouble relating it to my comment!

Comment: I'll be wondering about this exchange for the next six months...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect there to be any difference between the two queries, but it really does depend on the optimizer for you DBMS. It may be that one of these forms prevents the optimizer from "seeing" the opportunity to use an index that the other form doesn't.

As @Jinesh says, you'd be better using whatever facilities are available in your DBMS to examine the plans the optimizer produces in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

User Explain plan to find that out.

Comment: +1 but I would expect Postgres to be smart enough to use the same execution plan for both

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are absolutely right, it does use same execution plan for both of these queries.

Answer (score 1):

The performance will change if you have indexes on `id`s and `x`'s.